# Can there be a function holomorphic around $0$ w/ this property?

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exist a function $f:D\to \Bbb{C}$ holomorphic in a nbhd around $0$...

$(i)$ that satisfies $f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = \frac{1}{n+1}$ for odd $n$, and $f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = \frac{1}{n}$ for even $n$  (for all $n$ large enough)?

$(ii)$ that satisfies $f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = \frac{n}{n+1}$ (for all $n$ large enough)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first set of conditions can be ruled out on the basis of [the principle of isolated zeros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_%28complex_analysis%29#Properties) : if there was such an $f$, then $0$ would be an accumulation point of the set $\lbrace z\mid f(z)-z=0\rbrace$, and thus you'd have $\forall z\in D$, $f(z)=z$. But then the  condition for odd $n$ cannot hold.

The second set of conditions can be rephrased as $f(z)=\frac1{1+z}$ for all $z\in\lbrace \frac1n\mid n>>1\rbrace$. Thus $\frac1{1+z}$ provides a solution on a neighborhood of $0$.